# How to concatenate N different 1D arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cross-validation

I am new to python. I have to implement k-fold cross validation in python. I am able to split the given data in k equal sized arrays but not able to concatenate the k-1 arrays which will be the training data set. I know about concatenate() in numpy but as k is determine on the fly not sure how to use it in this scenario. Appreciate any info in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of an input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Check out numpy.vstack.  This stacks an iterable of arrays on top of each other (assuming the column dimensions match).  hstack does the opposite.
    import numpy as np

```
k = 10
all_data = [np.random.random((10,5)) for i in range(k)]

train = all_data[:k-1] #list of 9 (10,5) arrays
test = all_data[k-1] #one (10,5) array

train = np.vstack(train) #stacks them on top of each other
print train.shape # one (90, 5) array
```

Comment: You may also consider the sklearn kfold cross validation implementation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html